# Show that : $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ converge in $L^1$

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

> **Theorem (Doob decomposition):** Let $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a submartingale integrable. Then the Doob decomposition of $X_n$ is given by $$X_n = M_n+A_n$$ where $(M_n)_{n \geq 0}$ a martingale, and $(A_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be an increasing process such that  $A_{0}=0$ is $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable. $A_{n+1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. and even more : $$ sup_{n} \mathbb {E}|M_n|<+\infty ~and ~ A_{\infty}\in L^1 \Leftrightarrow sup_{n} \mathbb {E}X_n^+<+\infty$$

Show that :

If $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ converge in $L^1 $ if and only if :

$\exists M\in L^1 $ such as: $\forall n\in\mathbb {N}~M_n= \mathbb {E}^{\mathcal{F}_n }M$  and $A_\infty\in L^1$

My effort :

$(\Rightarrow ) $ $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ converge in $L^1 $ then, according to the definition of the limit, we have : 
$$
sup_{n} \mathbb {E}|X_n|<+\infty
$$
According to what is framed above we have:
$$
sup_{n} \mathbb {E}|M_n|<+\infty ~~and~~A_{\infty}\in L^1
$$

Now, $(M_n)_n $ is a martingale, then $M_n\to M_{\infty}$ almoust sure and $ M_{\infty}\in L^{1} $.

Let $n\in \mathbb {N}$, $(M_n)_n $ is a martingale, then $\forall p>n~:~~M_n=\mathbb {E}^{\mathcal{F}_n }M_p $
by passage to the limit, we have : 
$$
M_n=\mathbb {E}^{\mathcal{F}_n }\lim_p M_p =\mathbb {E}^{\mathcal{F}_n }M_{\infty}
$$

$(\Leftarrow ) $ we have : $X_n^+=(M_n+A_n)^+\leq M_n^+ +A_n\leq M_n^+ +A_{\infty} $ because $A_n \geq 0$ a.s. Then :
$$
\mathbb {E}X_n^+\leq \mathbb {E}M_n+\mathbb {E}A_{\infty}=\mathbb {E}M+\mathbb {E}A_{\infty}
$$
Because  $M_n= \mathbb {E}^{\mathcal{F}_n }M$ .
Then :
$$
sup_n \mathbb {E}X_n^+\leq \infty ~~(*)
$$

According to  $(X_n)_n $ is sub-martingale and $(*) $, we have : $(X_n)_n\to X_\infty $ with $X_\infty\in L^1$ .

My problem is to show that :

$$
\mathbb {E}|X_n- X_\infty|\to 0
$$
And thank you in advance.

I have another idea but I can't get applied, this idea is to show that:  $\{X_n~:~n\in \mathbb {N}\}$ is uniformly integrable.
We have $\{M_n~:~n \in\mathbb {N}\}$ is uniformly integrable Because $M_n= \mathbb {E}^{\mathcal{F}_n }M$ .

My problem is to show that : $\{A_n~:~n \in\mathbb {N}\}$ is uniformly integrable

Comment: You can prove that $A_n$ is uniformly integrable.

For instance, $\int_{\omega \in \Omega | A_{n} > c} |A_n| \leq \int_{\omega \in \Omega | A_{n+1} > c} |A_{n+1}| \leq ... \leq \int_{\omega \in \Omega | A_{\infty}> c} |A_{\infty}| = \int \mathbb{I}_{A_{\infty}(\omega) > c} |A_{\infty}| \leq \mu\{A_{\infty}(\omega) > c\}||A_{\infty}||_{L^1} \to 0$. as $c \to \infty$

We used the Holder inequality on $\mathbb{I}_{A_{\infty}(\omega) > c} |A_{\infty}| $

Comment: holder inequality  in $L^1$?

Comment: $p = \infty, q = 1$ version of the inequality